# Rewriting trigonometric function in terms of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, trigonometry

Let's consider function for $c, a_1, a_2,...,a_n, b_1,...,b_n \in \mathbb R$

$$g(x) = c + a_1\sin x + b_1 \cos x + a_2 \sin(2x) + b_2 \cos(2x) + ...+ a_n \sin(nx) + b_n \cos(nx)$$

And complex number $z = \cos(x) + i \sin(x)$

I want to rewrite function $g$ using only terms $z$ (it should be polynomial of degree $2n$).

What I'm almost sure about is that we have to use De' Moivre formula:

$$z^n = |z^n| (\cos(n \alpha) + i \sin(n\alpha))$$

However, the problem is presence of numbers $a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2,...$ standing in front of the trigonometric objects in function $g$. I wanted to consider function $$g \prod_{i = 1}^n a_ib_i$$

but it doesn't change a lot of and it's not helping to rewrite $g$ in terms of $z$. Could I please ask you for a hand in doing so?

**EDIT**

As suggested in comments I tried to rewrite this in form of Laurent series, we know that:

$$e^{ikx} = \cos(kx) + i \sin(kx)$$

and $e^{x} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$

Out of those facts we'll have that:

$$\cos(kx) + i \sin(kx) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(ikx)^n}{n!}$$

But here I don't know what to do next? Am I going into right direction? I'm not sure how to say that right side expression is a polynomial of degree $k$

Comment: Is it $\ldots +a_n \sin(nx)+b_n\cos(nx)$?

Comment: Yes it is, I corrected the question ;))

Comment: You can write it as a Laurent polynomial in $z$ using $e^{ixk}=\cos(kx)+i\sin(kx)$.

Comment: Have you tried or seen solving your equation for $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ in terms of $z$? Do you know Euler's Theorem (not necessary but helpful)?

Comment: You mean that $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i \sin(x)$? I also thought about it but I don't see the application of it

Comment: I updated my question, could you please have a look at it?

Comment: Use the fact that if $z=e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$, then $z^k=e^{ikx}=\cos(kx)+i\sin(kx)$, so $\cos(kx)=\frac{z^k+\overline{z^k}}{2}$ and $\sin(kx)=\frac{z^k-\overline{z^k}}{2i}$. Now, you can plug this into your expression to get something in terms of $z$ and $\overline{z}$ (a polynomial in $z$ and $\overline{z}$, of degree at most $n$).

Comment: @John I said Laurent *polynomial* in $e^{ix}$ and not Laurent *series* in $x$. peek-a-boo's comment will give you the Laurent polynomial since $\bar z =1/z$ in your case.